# How to AUTOMATICALLY open all links (flash streams) in different tabs or windows IE9, Safari, or Firefox?

Tags: browser-tabs

Is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY open all links in a given website in different tabs or windows?

I've tried "snap link plus",  but it didn't work on this particular website:

http://www.teledunet.com

To open others streams on this website (found on the left hand side of the page), you would need to login using (cmoi123 / 12345) by clicking on "Connexion" on the top right side of the main page).

Thank You In Advance!

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, I would recommend Greasemonkey (I think it has ports to other browsers also).  A simple script would look like this:

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0;i<;links.length;i++)
    links[i].target="_blank";
```

This changes the target of every link to open in a new window or new tab (based on your browser preferences).

Comment: Thanks Man! BUT have you tried this using the website and the login credentials I've provided? This isn't your "standard" website...I have downloaded greamonkey FF add-on, clicked on new user script, BUT I have no idea what to do next or how to start this thing!!! Can you please dumb it down for me? Where do I put the name of the website (www.teledunet.com) or where to specify that I want those links (on the left hand side) to open AUTOMATICALLY w/o me clicking on each one of them....Thanks Again!

Comment: When you click New User Script, you should get a dialog with Name, Namespace, Description, Includes, and Excludes.  For Name and Description, put anything that you want.  Namespace is just to distinguish between different scripts with the same name; you can just put your name.  Put http://teledunet.com/* for Includes and leave Excludes blank.  Press OK and copy the code I wrote into the next window.  Save, and everything should work.

Comment: Ok I did what you've suggested saved the script, then opened the website, but I got a greasemonkey thing that says something about @grant and metadata!! I have no idea what's that about, but the 235 links did not open! Only the main page video opened!

Comment: Sorry; I thought that you meant to have the links automatically open in a new tab when you clicked them (as opposed to in the same tab).  See my next answer.

Comment: All 235 links should open automatically in new separate tabs w/o me having to click on each and everyone of them (otherwise it defeats the purpose to have to click ea link)...Thanks for helping...please try it...I gave you the login credentials for testing purposes...I don't see your "next answer" bro! Did you post it already?

Comment: SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM, since you seem to know your s**t maybe you can help me out with this... Can one get a script that deletes specific lines (e.g. line 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 17, etc...hundreds of them) from a txt file, then replace the deleted lines with specific lines (also different) from a 2nd txt file? Thanks Again! Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/504101/batch-replace-specific-line-s-in-an-xml-with-specific-text-lines-from-a-2nd-x THANKS MAN!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the website, and I assume that you are talking about the channel links on the left (correct me if I am wrong).  Unfortunately, those are Javascript links, which means that they operate on the current page, rather than taking you to a new page.  Therefore, there is no way to open them in a new tab (you can verify that by trying to open one in a new tab manually; some browsers will refuse to do anything, and some will just open a blank page).  This is also why Snap Links Plus did not work.  Unless you can find a way to do it manually, there is no way to do it automatically.

Also, opening that many pages at once is generally a bad idea.  Opening too many at once can do bad things to a browser (such as hanging it), so I can only imagine what 235 would do!

Comment: Thanks SPAM! I thought I'd try anyway...I'm trying to catch all those rtmp links and dump them into a file...and I'd hate to do that manually, so I thought there may be a way to automate that process, but I guess not :( If you can think of any other way to do that hit me... Thanks Again!

Comment: SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM, since you seem to know your s**t  :) maybe you can help me out with this... Can one get a script that deletes specific lines (e.g. line 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 17, etc...hundreds of them) from a txt file, then replace the deleted lines with specific lines (also different) from a 2nd txt file? Thanks Again! Also see: superuser.com/questions/504101/… THANKS MAN!